# Dephi: Passing a data pointer to a comboboxitem

Tags: delphi, pointers, combobox, vcl

I want to bind a object to an Item.
I allready saw this functionality in TListView, but I couldn't find it in TComboBox.
Is there a way to bind an object to a comboBoxItem in delphi?
Note that I'm using vcl.

Comment: You can use the Objects properly of the TStrings property Items. Often better though to separate the data from the UI that presents it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AddObject` method of combobox `Items` property.

```
var
  pt : Pointer;
begin
//...
  myCombobox.Items.AddObject('Some string', pt);
```

Be aware however, that using this method to store interface pointers is unsafe because it ignores reference counting.